# How is this linear transformation defined?

Tags: linear-transformations

In a paper I am reading, it says: *"Consider the linear transformation that takes the x-axis to the line $y = mx$ and leaves the y-axis fixed"*.

He is talking about $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $m\in \mathbb{R}$ is a previously defined constant.

Given a point $p=(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, what is the result of applying the described transformation to $p$?

Comment: Have you tried $T(x,y) = m$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja what is $T$? if you mean that $T$ is the described transformation, then note that the result should be a point, not a single number.

Comment: Hm, what is $T(0,0)$? The point $(0,0)$ is both on the $x$-axis and on the $y$-axis. If it is supposed to be mapped to the line $y=m$ with $m\neq 0$, than $T$ maps $(0,0)$ to something that is not $(0,0)$. Thus, it cannot be linear. I misunderstand the question, maybe?

Comment: @mickep you are right. I wrote the line's equation wrong, it should be y=mx (it is corrected now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it takes x-axis to the line $y=m$, it transforms the vector 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}to the vector
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
m
\end{bmatrix}
It leaves the y-axis fixed. That means 
$$T\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Combing the above, we have 
$$TI=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
m & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
So 
$$T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
m & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now apply $T$ on $p$, you will get the resulting point.

Comment: Note that there was a typo in the question, the line should be $y=mx$ instead of $y=m$

Comment: Sorry my mistake. This is in fact the answer for $y=mx$.