# What linear transformation achieves this?

Tags: linear-transformations

Given a set $S=\{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n\}$ of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\alpha_i$ be the angle between $l_i$ and the positive direction of the $x$-axis ($-\pi/2\leq\alpha_i<\pi/2$).

Give a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that by applying this transformation we can have at least half of the lines with nonnegative angles and at least half of the lines with nonpositive angles.

---

**Additional details**: in the paper I am reading it says that *"the linear transformation that takes the $x$-axis to the line $y=\alpha_mx$ and leaves the $y$-axis fixed"*, where $\alpha_m$ is the median of $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, achieves this.

According to the question

[How is this linear transformation defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101156/how-is-this-linear-transformation-defined/1101168#1101168)

the translation that does that is $T(x,y)=(x,y+\alpha_m x)$. However, according to the following reasoning (that may be wrong), this is not correct:

Suppose that there is a single line $l_1$ which is the line that goes through $(1,0),(2,1)$. The line $l_1$ forms an angle of $\pi/4$ with the $x$-axis, and so $\alpha_1=\alpha_m$ is $\pi/4$. However, if we apply $T$ to $l_1$, we obtain the line that goes through $T((1,0)) = (1,0)$ and $T((2,1)) = (2,1+\pi/2)$, which clearly forms a positive angle with the $x$-axis, and thus the conclusion that "we can have at least half of our lines with nonpositive angles" does not hold.

Comment: In your reference to the paper, "the linear transformation that takes the x-axis to the line $y=\alpha_m x$ and leaves the y-axis fixed", where $\alpha_m$ is the median .....", I think "takes the line $y=\alpha_m x$ to x-axis" sounds more reasonable to me.

Comment: @KittyL I quotted it literally. It is from the paper "Linear-time algorithms for linear programming in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and related problems", by Nimrod Megiddo (beginning of section 4.3)

Comment: Also I think the $\alpha_m$ might be $\tan{\alpha_m}$. I am not very sure yet. It's an interesting problem. But intuitively, think about a bunch of lines passing through origin, if your linear transformation drag the middle one to x-axis, it would somehow achieve the result. But that requires the changes I suggested. Also it would work for your example.

Comment: I read that section of the paper. I think it is a minor mistake in the paper.

Comment: @KittyL What is the correct transformation then (i.e. the original question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "median theory" is correct, the correct statement is: "the linear transformation that takes the line $y=mx$ to x-axis and leaves the y-axis fixed", where $m=\tan{\alpha_m}$ and $\alpha_m$ is the median of $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n$, achieves this."

The linear transformation that takes the line $y=mx$ to $x$-axis and leaves the $y$-axis fixed is

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-m & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Does not seem correct. If, for instance, $S=\{l_1,l_2\}$, where $l_1$ goes through $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, and $l_2$ goes through $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$, we have $\alpha_1 = 0.785, \alpha_2 = 0, \alpha_m = 0.392$, and then $T(l_1)$ has angle $0.529$ and $T(l_2)$ has angle $0.169$, both positive.

Comment: That is not correct. $T(l_2)$ has angle -0.393.

Comment: You are right, it was a calculation mistake. By the way, I am surprised that the median of the angles after the mapping is not 0.

Comment: Yeah, the whole structure is kind of deformed.